# Border box sizing in firefox

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get my login form all aligned in a column.  This works great in Chrome and (hilariously) IE but doesnt in Firefox!

Can anyone help me out with what the issue is?

You can see it here in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8F5fh/)!

I am currently using border box to get everything aligned in spite of padding.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox still uses the prefixed version, so add `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` before your `box-sizing` declaration.

Comment: Is there a JS plugin that will do all the vendor prefixing for me?

Comment: Using JS will be slower than just using prefixes in your CSS.

Comment: @Chris - What cimmanon said. That said, you might want to look into a CSS preprocessor such as LESS or Sass, if you're going to do a lot of fancy stuff with CSS3. They provide mixins for dealing with vendor prefixing.

Comment: all you have to do to fix the vendor prefixing if you are worried that you have a lot of box-sizing rules is just a find and replace in your css file. replace the old instances of box-sizing with the box-sizing & vendor prefix box-sizing rules should handle it in one quick shot.

Comment: @Chris with a good IDE / text editor, you could find all occurences of `box-sizing: border-box;` and append `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` to them. Done within 5 seconds !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `-moz-` prefix for Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

If you are into responsive design, include these also for wider coverage of browsers on mobile devices.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
/* Safari 3.0 - 5.0, Chrome 1 - 9, Android 2.1 - 3.x */

-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
/* Firefox 1 - 28 */

box-sizing: border-box;
/* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+, Firefox 29+, Opera 7+, IE 8+, Android 4.0+, iOS any */
```